# CSS - PHP Header Include File Not Fitting Device Size/Reaching Whole Width

Tags: php, css, mobile

The following code is part of a include file that has a header for a website.

```
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Test Site | Foo The Bar </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="csss_standard.css">
</head>

<body>

<div id="big_wrapper">



    <header id="Header">
        <a href="homepage.php"><img src="home_page_art.png" alt="Logo"></a>
    </header> 

    <div id="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li id="page_1"><a href="page1.php">Page 1</a></li>
            |
            <li id="page_2"><a href="page_2">Page 2</a></li>
            |
            <li id="Page_3"><a href="page_3.php">Page 3</a></li>
            |
            <li id="page_4"><a href="page_4">Page 4</a></li>
            |
            <li id="news"><a href="news_and_such.php">Page 5</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div> 

</div>

<br>
<br>

</body>
```

On the desktop site this looks great. Everything sizes properly. But when it comes to getting it on a mobile site, the site seems to size to the central "meat and potatoes" div where I put all the content. The div is one column, and its width is explicitly declared as 1000px as seen below.

```
#meat_and_potatoes{
display:block;
text-align:center;
padding: 15px;
width:1000px;
text-align:center;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
float:center;
background:#D8D8D8;
box-shadow: 1px 0px 20px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);

}
```

header and #Header div css below.

```
#Header{
margin: 0px 0px;
display:block;
width:105%; <!-- this was originally not a property. I was toying around with it to no avail... -->

/* orange gradiant */

background: rgb(255, 180, 0);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(255, 180, 0) 51%, rgb(255, 216, 0) 100%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(255, 180, 0) 51%, rgb(255, 216, 0) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(255, 180, 0) 51%, rgb(255, 216, 0) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(255, 180, 0) 51%, rgb(255, 216, 0) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(255, 180, 0) 51%, rgb(255, 216, 0) 100%);

height: auto;
float:left;
padding-left:10px;
}



header, section, footer, aside, nav, article, hgroup{
display:block;
}
```

As I said above, the mobile view auto-fits to this center div. Does mobile like explicitly declared widths? Could the issue lie in the code for the header being in an .inc? (I rather doubt it simply because I have tested the source in the actual page below just about every div tag) Could it be an issue with mobile vs. desktop CSS views? (E.G the "screen" rel type)

I realize there is a lot of moving parts to this problem, so if something else is needed, please let me know.

Comment: Hey Andrew why don't you optimize the site for mobile? Then you don't need to worry how desktop css is affecting the mobile css. Just use "media queries" :)

Comment: @damienhawks That is what I meant above! I just forgot the word haha :) So you suggest addapting one css for mobile (up to say 800 px) and one for desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andrew hope this gives you a better idea about the sizes for which you should write a media query:-

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
}
```

Write media queries depending on the audience you want to cater too, i would select the first one if i had to write just one, because it covers most smartphones. Please go ahead and clear any doubts you have and ask me anything you feel like about this. Would love to help you further.

Comment: Wow! What a great resource my friend. Is there a way to lock the orientation of the page to only portrait or is it best practice to write out the landscape orientation as well? (I think I may have answered my own question. Just wanted your opinion.)

Comment: I think writing a common one for both is sufficient. But then depends some people like to consider all views, I've seen most use portrait rather than landscape. I would encourage you to check this out:- http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-use-orientation-on-your-mobile-sites/ and i hope that answers your query, if not please comment again :D